# How do I plot a Laplace transform?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework, integral-transforms

I have been looking everywhere for help on this issue and cannot find a solution that works. Here is the assignment.

[image: Here is the homework assignment]

I have figured out how to find the Laplace transform, but I do not know how to graph it. Here is my code:

```
de1 = 25 x''[t] + 10 x'[t] + 226 x[t] == 901*Cos[3 t];
inits = {x[0] -> 0, x'[0] -> 0};
DE = LaplaceTransform[de1, t, s]
X = Solve[DE, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]]
X = X // Last // Last // Last
X = X /. inits
f1 = InverseLaplaceTransform[X, s, t] // Expand
```

And here is the resulting inverse Laplace transform, or the solution (I think):

> ```
> (-(1/2) - (451 I)/30) E^((-(1/5) - 3 I) t) - 
>   (1/2 - (451 I)/30) E^((-(1/5) + 3 I) t) + Cos[3 t] + 30 Sin[3 t]
> ```

But how do I graph it?

Comment: Your link shows that this is a homework assignment.  This is not a site for us to do your homework assignments.  (Vote to close.)

Comment: what's you range for plotting on both axes !?

Comment: If you can't figure out your homework you can always ask the stack exchange, vote to close  :(

Comment: It's not that I don't know how to do my homework, I just needed help with the Mathematica/coding portion of it.

Comment: Clearly I showed my code, meaning I know how to solve the equation. I was providing the homework problem to provide context.

Comment: @StephanieGreen For what it's worth, I agree: yours was not a "gimme da codez" kind of question. You included your code attempts and showed effort. I hope that this community's initial response did not alienate you, and I am looking forward to further contributions from you!

Comment: Seems to me to be a legitimate question!  How to graph a function in *Mathematica*.  Isn't this the type of question that this site is here for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying your exact code

```
de1 = 25*Derivative[2][x][t] + 10*Derivative[1][x][t] + 226*x[t] == 901*Cos[3*t]; 

inits = {x[0] -> 0, Derivative[1][x][0] -> 0}; 

DE = LaplaceTransform[de1, t, s]

X = Solve[DE, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]]

X = Last[Last[Last[X]]]

X = X /. inits

f1 = Simplify[Expand[InverseLaplaceTransform[X, s, t]]]
```

Now it's easy to plot as range from 0

```
Plot[f1, {t, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!